# Vuejs multiples file upload uploading just 1 file at the time

Tags: vue.js, asp.net-core, axios, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm working on a VueJS Application and I'm using net core as backend,

I have a component with an upload function that is working but not as expected, for example, if i chose to upload 3 files it would upload just the first out of 3.

My HTML

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="large-12 medium-12 small-12 cell">
          <label>
            Files
            <input type="file" name="file" ref="files" multiple v-on:change="fileChange($event.target.files)" />
          </label>
          <v-btn outline color="primary" dark v-on:click="upload()">Submit</v-btn>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Part of my script

```
  export default {
    name: 'Profile',
    data() {
      return {
        records: [],
        application: [],
        profile: [],
        history: [],
        userValues: [],
        dialog: false,
        notifications: false,
        sound: true,
        widgets: false,
        files: new FormData()        
      };
    },
    methods: {

        });
      }
```

And my Controller

```
 [Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class UploadController : Controller
{
    private IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;

    public UploadController(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
    {
        _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
    }

                {
                    file.CopyTo(stream);
                }
            }
            return Json("Upload Successful.");
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            return Json("Upload Failed: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Also along with the files, I would like to pass email: this.profile.email as a parameter from my vue.

Like I said it is working but just one file at the time.

Answer (score 0):

`var file = Request.Form.Files[0];` That will pop off only the first file from your request. Instead, you need to check for

Instead access your files in a loop:

```
foreach(uploadedFile in Request.Form.Files) {

}
```